# Visual Studio 2019 How do I choose Clang to be the toolchain?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I want to create a Visual Studio project, compile with Clang and run on Windows.

I was trying to following this guide:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/clang-llvm-support-in-visual-studio/

But after an introduction to installation it suddenly mentions CMake.

So far I have:

1. Installed VS2019 (choosing Clang tools for Windows option)
2. Created an Empty C++ project

How do I now instruct my project to use Clang?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In each project's "Properties" pop-up, select "LLVM (clang-cl)" as the "Platform Toolset" to use, as shown below:

[image]

If you don't see this option, then you (probably) need to add more of the 'optional' Clang-related components, *via* your Visual Studio Installer (select "Modify" and list "Individual Components"):

[image]

You'll need the "Clang-cl for v142 build tools..." at the very least.

Comment: Hey Adrian, I need to build my Boost libraries. I'm following an online video and he opens a special cmd which sets VS environment variables. However, will this install Boost for MSVC, rather than clang? I'm missing libboost_date_time-clangw10-mt-gd-x32-1_73.li

Comment: After checking that all those items were added in (and adding in the couple that were missing), I still don't have a "Platform Toolset" line --- does this require creating a new solution?